# Eigenvalues with absolute values close to 1

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a generalized eigen-problem: $A\psi = \lambda B \psi$ with $A$ and $B$ are large (>1000) complex non-Hermitian matrices. I know that eigenvalues with largest and smallest absolute values can be found using iterative approaches like ARPACK. But I am only interested in those complex eigenvalues (not all of them) with absolute values closest to 1. It there any fast and parallel approach to do this?

Comment: Are they dense or sparse matrices ?

Comment: have you looked at the [shift-invert mode](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/UG/node33.html) of ARPACK?

Comment: @GoHokies Yes, I know the shift-invert mode of ARPACK, but it is only useful for eigen values near some number. But here my question is about the eigen values with **absolute** values (not the value) around 1.

Comment: @percusse Both the A and B matrices are dense.

Comment: @YunpengWang shift-invert is used to find the eigenvalues nearest to the shift _in absolute value_.

Comment: How large are your matrices really? 1000 does not strike me as particularly large today.